# Find nearest locations from json Sencha Touch 2

Tags: google-maps-api-3, extjs, sencha-touch-2, distance

I'm trying to setup a portion to my app where the user's mobile location (which I have working) is used to find the nearest locations (lets say within 15 miles) against a json store of locations (lets say of 40 or so and it will increase). 
I've been racking my brain how to go about this. I believe Distance Matrix (looking at the Google API, but no idea how to implement it from the docs) is something I need, but I can't figure how to load the json list and use it against the location (still a n00b). 
If there's a tutorial or some details on how to go about it would be great. I just need a point in the right direction.
Any info is great, thanks ahead of time.
I'm using Sencha Touch 2.0.1, a json store and using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off doing that processing on the backend and sending only the close records back to the client. This will keep your client app from getting bogged down.

You can use Postgresql/Postgis for this if you store the lat/long points as spatial data. You can also do this with the MySQL spatial extensions. If you want to build the haversine formula into a MySQL function, you can draw 15 mile radii around all of your points and use MySQL's builtin 'within' function. If you'd rather use a flavor of NoSQL, then CouchDB has a nice GeoCouch extension which can perform the function you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, figured out a way. More than likely not the best, but it'll work for now.
I'm loading all the latitudes and longitudes with the locations into the store file.
Then, on initialize, it takes the current location and matches it against the stored locations and runs the Haversine formula with each one.  Once it has all of the distances, it sorts and done.